# Proxy.php not working w/ AJAX Solr

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, solr, proxy

I am trying to access a Solr 4.5.0 instance that rests on a  private server,

```
http://12.34.56.789:8983/
```

My application is located on this web server,

```
http://www.mywebapp.com
```

That said, I elected to use JavaScript library AJAX Solr to make the initial call to access the JSON object that's within that Solr instance.

I know that running an AJAX call to a different domain is out of the question, so I elected to run with a PHP proxy that compliments the JS framework. In essence, proxy.php, https://gist.github.com/evolvingweb/298580

I've included the necessary SolrPhpClient code base, stored it in the same directory as the proxy.php file and modified line 43,

```
$solr = new Apache_Solr_Service('www.mywebapp.com', 80, '/js/');
```

Obviously, I am not seeing the JSON publishing to the search results page and would like to get some insight on how to integrate this correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In the javascript where you initiate `AjaxSolr` replace `solrURL` with `proxyURL`:

```
Manager = new AjaxSolr.Manager({
  proxyUrl: 'http://localhost/subdirectory/proxy.php'
});
```

In proxy.php, line 49:

```
$solr = new Apache_Solr_Service('http://example.com', 80, '/pathToSolr/solr/' . $core);
```

[This information is taken from this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ajax-solr/27zGr9aqCxQ).